# Spring ldaptemplate unable to delete attribute with multiple values

Tags: azure-active-directory, active-directory, ldap, spring-ldap

I want to delete attribute with multiple values but it ignores this while successfully deletes another attribute with specific value in directory.

```
Attribute attr1 = new BasicAttribute("fooAttr");
ModificationItem attr1mod = new 
ModificationItem(DirContext.REMOVE_ATTRIBUTE,attr1);
Attribute attr2 = new BasicAttribute("barAttr","my value");
ModificationItem attr2mod = new 
ModificationItem(DirContext.REMOVE_ATTRIBUTE,attr2);
try{ 
    ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes("cn=myname,dc=example,dc=com", new 
    ModificationItem[]{attr1mod, attr2mod});
    } catch(Exception e) {
    // 
}
```

barAttr is deleted with the specified value but multivalued fooAttr is not deleted.

barAttr is also multivalued and the specified value is deleted. I also tried to delete a specified value of fooAttr and still it failed to delete the specified value of fooAttr. I confirmed externally that fooAttr exists in the directory.

ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes executes successfully, does not throw exception.

If I do this:

```
ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes("cn=myname,dc=example,dc=com", new 
    ModificationItem[]{attr1mod});
```

then in this case exception is thrown:

LDAP: error code 16 - Failed to modify the underlying source: No such attribute

UPDATE
I also tried this approach:

```
DirContextOperation context = ldaptemplate.lookup(dn);
String [] fooAttrValues = context.getStringAttributes("fooAttr");

for(String value : fooattrValues) {
  context.removeAttributeValue("fooAttr", value);
}
String [] fooAttrValues2 = context.getStringAttributes("fooAttr");
```

This does not work, after program is run the director still has the same attribute and all the values. I debugged through it, it does get the correct values but does not remove any value, even fooAttrValues2 still has all the values.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I think to delete specific attribute values, you better to use the `DirContext.REMOVE_ATTRIBUTE` flag for each value individually, right now, you are using `DirContext.REMOVE_ATTRIBUTE` flag for both attributes `attr1` and `attr2` in your code and it used to remove the entire attribute, not specific attribute values!

something like this:

```
Attribute attr1 = new BasicAttribute("fooAttr", "value1"); 
ModificationItem attr1mod = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REMOVE_ATTRIBUTE, attr1);

Attribute attr2 = new BasicAttribute("barAttr", "my value"); 
ModificationItem attr2mod = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REMOVE_ATTRIBUTE, attr2);

try {
    ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes("cn=myname,dc=example,dc=com", new ModificationItem[]{attr1mod, attr2mod});
} catch (Exception e) {
    //here handle your exceptions
}
```

**Update**
and also, instead of using the `REMOVE_ATTRIBUTE`,you can try using the `REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE` with the modified list of values for `fooAttr`.it involves retrieving the existing attribute values, removing the specific value you want to delete, and then using `REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE` to update `fooAttr` with the modified list!

```
ModificationItem attr1mod = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REMOVE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute("fooAttr"));

//removing a specific value of the multi-valued attribute
ModificationItem attr2mod = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REMOVE_ATTRIBUTE | DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute("barAttr", "my value"));

ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes("cn=myname,dc=example,dc=com", new ModificationItem[]{attr1mod, attr2mod});
```

Comment: Freeman, thanks but as mentioned in the post ; "I also tried to delete a specified value of fooAttr and still it failed to delete the specified value of fooAttr. I confirmed externally that fooAttr exists in the directory." whic is exactly what your code is doing bu fails to delete even specific value of fooAttr.

Comment: so try using a different LDAP client, such as Apache Directory Studio, to perform the same modification and see if you encounter the same issue. and check my answer again plz.

Comment: ldaptemplate.getattributes does not exist. I tried similar approach but does not work either.

Comment: @ace oh, yes, I apologize. It was a piece of another project that I copied and pasted that night, and it was a mistake. I have updated the code again. Could you please check if the problem is resolved with the new code? thnx

Comment: your code is very similar to my code in the post. So still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, have you checked if youve got the right permissions to mess with `fooAttr`? Sometimes LDAP can be a bit sneaky like that, and it doesn't let just anyone tweak everyhting.

Also, there might be some quirky  rules set in teh LDAP schema. Like, maybe, it's mandatory for `fooAttr` to always have somevalue? Worth a look.

We can try updating the code as below:

```
DirContextOperations context = ldapTemplate.lookupContext("cn=myname,dc=example,dc=com");
List<String> currentValues = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(context.getStringAttributes("fooAttr")));

for (String val : new ArrayList<>(currentValues)) {
    currentValues.remove(val);
    context.setAttributeValues("fooAttr", currentValues.toArray(new String[0]));
}

ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(context);
```

A heads up, if things still act weird, try turning on debug mode for Spring LDAP. Might catch something fishy there. You can also dive deep and try to make a few changes straight on LDAP server using command line.

Hope this helps. Finger crossed.